# React - "You need to enable Javascript to run this app."

Tags: reactjs

I always get this in a noscript-Tag in my react projects.

- I even created a complete new one with ***npx create-react-app
  my-app***.

It still has this tag.

- I then ***added*** this ***"homepage": "."*** line in my
  package.json, but this didnt fix it neither.
- Of course I enabled it in my browser. (I used different browsers aswell)

So what should I do to fix this?

Comment: Does this line affect me? (Because I didnt notice anything till now)

Comment: The `<noscript>` tag's content should only display when JavaScript is disabled.

Comment: Yeah, but I mean the javascript should work when I didnt notice it till now. So it shouldt affect me?

Comment: If the message displays when you view the page in the browser, that's a problem, because React uses JavaScript to do its thing. I'd say if you're seeing the message when running the app, you could add code that hides it: `window.addEventListener('load', () => document.querySelector('noscript').style.display = 'none');`, but it shouldn't be necessary...

Comment: But I used "a lot" of javascript code in my last project and there were no issues.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fallback option added by npx and it will be displayed in browsers that can't run JavaScript. This will most likely never make a difference nowadays. However, you can test this by temporarilly disabling JavaScript.

You can check the [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/noscript) documentation to find out more about the `<noscript>` tag.